# C++ constexpr at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

Am I right to think that this function should only be evaluated at compile time, or is there a run-time cost to it?

```
template <typename T>
size_t constexpr CompID() {
    return typeid(T).hash_code();
}

struct Foo {};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    size_t foo = CompID<Foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

constexpr function allows the function to be evaluated at compile time, but does not require that, so your answer is "maybe". It depends on the compiler's optimization settings.

> #### §7.1.5[dcl.constexpr]/7
>
> A call to a `constexpr` function produces the same result as a call to an equivalent non-`constexpr` function
>   in all respects except that a call to a `constexpr` function can appear in a constant expression.

If you wish to have no runtime cost, you could force compile-time evaluation by assigning it to a constexpr variable, e.g.

```
constexpr auto foo = CompID<Foo>();
```

Also note that `type_info.hash_code()` **cannot be evaluated in compile-time** (it is not a constexpr function, §18.7.1[type.info]/7). So your code is actually wrong.

Comment: Thanks you very much for a quick and informative answer. Can you think of any workaround to get the hash of a type at compile time?

Comment: @sharvey: Why do you need such a hash? Maybe you could use template specialization in those places instead?

Comment: Using the hash as key in a map.

Comment: @sharvey: You can neither build nor access a map via hash at compile-time either. Don't start thinking that `constexpr` means "I can do anything at compile-time". It's very limited, *on purpose*.

Comment: @sharvey A "compile-time map" can be easily constructed using specialization. See the `type2int` struct in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1708628/224671 for example.

Comment: @NicolBolas: not sure why it's on purpose.