# Force constexpr to be evaluated at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

```
#include <algorithm>

struct S
{
    static constexpr int X = 10;
};

int main()
{
    return std::min(S::X, 0);
};
```

If `std::min` expects a `const int&`, the compiler very likely would like to have the `S::X` also defined somewhere, i.e. the storage of `S::X` must exists.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452952/c-linker-error-with-class-static-constexpr) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785691/c-constexpr-at-compile-time).

Is there a way to *force* the compiler to evaluate my `constexpr` at compile time?

The reason is:

Initially, we had a problem in early initialization of static variables in the init priority. There was some `struct Type<int> { static int max; };`, and some global `static int x = Type<int>::max;`, and some other early code `other_init` used that `x`. When we updated GCC, suddenly we had `x == 0` in `other_init`.

We thought that we could avoid the problem by using `constexpr`, so that it would always evaluate it at compile time.

The only other way would be to use `struct Type<int> { static constexpr int max(); };` instead, i.e. letting it be a function.

Comment: `constexpr` doesn't fix the Static Initialization Order Fiasco.

Comment: Can you post the code which is giving you problems? I mean the one with struct Type<int>. I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @MarcoA.: What code do you mean? It's already there. Let `other_init` be `__attribute__((constructor))` and just `printf("%i", x);`.

Answer (score 3):

For types that are allowed to exist as template value parameters, you can introduce a data structure like this:

```
template <typename T, T K>
struct force
{
    static constexpr T value = K;
};
```

Usage:

```
force<int, std::min(S::X, 0)>::value
```

Answer (score 2):

The `constexpr` is evaluated at compile time.  Your problem is
due to the fact that `std::min` is not a `constexpr`, so
regardless of its input, the results are not a const expression
(and in particular, if you initialize a variable with static
lifetime using `std::min`, it is dynamic initialization).

The simplest solution is probably to define your own `min`,
something along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T staticMin( T a, T b )
{
    return a > b ? b : a;
}
```

This should result in full evaluation at compile time, and
static initialization.

Comment: My question is not really about `std::min`. That is just an example. I don't want to duplicate all of STL. Also, it doesn't matter that the result of `std::min` is not a const expression. I don't want/need/asked for the evaluation of `std::min` at compile time.

Comment: So what is your question?  In your example code, `S::X` is a compile time constant, and it is evaluated at compile time.  What isn't evaluated at compile time is `std::min`, because `std::min` isn't `constexpr`.

Comment: I don't care that `std::min` is not evaluated at compile time. `S::X` is not evaluated at compile time, otherwise the linker would not complain about the missing symbol. See also my linked questions, maybe they make it more clear.

Comment: Except that `S::x` _is_ evaluated at compile time.  The reason the linker complains about the missing symbol is because the interface to `std::min` requires its address (indirectly, via a reference argument).  (If the compiler doesn't "look into" `std::min`, it must assume that it might contain something like `&arg == &S::X`.  Which must evaluate to `true`, so the compiler cannot pass a reference to a local temporary.)

Comment: I think we understand "evaluated at compile time" differently. See the linked questions, esp [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8452990/133374) answer. I basically mean that the expression of `S::X` gets inlined. As if you would have written `std::min(10, 0)`. That is the same meaning as in the linked answer. If that requires a `const T&`, it will use the address on the stack.

Comment: @Albert I think we understand "evaluate" differently. The subexpression   `S::X` in the expression `std::min(S::X, 0)` is an lvalue that refers to the integer `S::X` declared as a static member in `S`. Since `std::min` accepts its arguments by reference without performing lvalue to rvalue conversion, that is what it means to evaluate `S::X` "at compile time." If you want that subexpression to be treated as a prvalue - so that the compiler creates a temporary object to pass by reference to `std::min` - it's easy enough to do so with `std::min(+S::X, 0)`.