# Is there a non-indirection, non-hack way to guarantee that a constexpr function only be callable at compile time?

Tags: c++, constexpr

At the moment, we have two primary options for compile-time evaluation: template metaprogramming (generally using template structs and/or variables), and `constexpr` operations<sup>1</sup>.

```
template<int l, int r> struct sum_ { enum { value = l + r }; }; // With struct.
template<int l, int r> const int sum = sum_<l, r>::value;       // With struct & var.
template<int l, int r> const int sub = l - r;                   // With var.
constexpr int mul(int l, int r) { return l * r; }               // With constexpr.
```

Of these, we are guaranteed that all four can be evaluated at compile time.

```
template<int> struct CompileTimeEvaluable {};

CompileTimeEvaluable<sum_<2, 2>::value> template_struct;                 // Valid.
CompileTimeEvaluable<sum<2, 2>>         template_struct_with_helper_var; // Valid.
CompileTimeEvaluable<sub<2, 2>>         template_var;                    // Valid.
CompileTimeEvaluable<mul(2, 2)>         constexpr_func;                  // Valid.
```

We can also guarantee that the first three will *only* be evaluable at compile time, due to the compile-time nature of templates; we cannot, however, provide this same guarantee for `constexpr` functions.

```
int s1 = sum_<1, 2>::value;
//int s2 = sum_<s1, 12>::value; // Error, value of i not known at compile time.

int sv1 = sum<3, 4>;
//int sv2 = sum<s1, 34>;        // Error, value of i not known at compile time.

int v1 = sub<5, 6>;
//int v2 = sub<v1, 56>;         // Error, value of i not known at compile time.

int c1 = mul(7, 8);
int c2 = mul(c1, 78);           // Valid, and executed at run time.
```

It is possible to [use indirection to provide an *effective* guarantee that a given `constexpr` function can only be called at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653251/5386374), but this guarantee breaks if the function is accessed directly instead of through the indirection helpers (as noted in the linked answer's comments).  It is also possible to [poison a `constexpr` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33964621/5386374) such that calling it at runtime becomes impossible, [by `throw`ing an undefined symbol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZjYCQ8dzTc&feature=youtu.be&t=3679), thus providing this guarantee by awkward hack.  Neither of these seems optimal, however.

---

Considering this, my question is thus: Including current standards, C++20 drafts, proposals under consideration, experimental features, and anything else of the sort, is there a way to provide this guarantee without resorting to hacks or indirection, using only features and tools built into and/or under consideration for being built into the language itself?  [Such as, for example, an attribute such as (both theoretical) `[[compile_time_only]]` or `[[no_runtime]]`, usage of [std::is_constant_evaluated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated), or a concept, perhaps?]

<sup>1: Macros are *technically* also an option, but... yeah, no.</sup>

Comment: Note: May be a duplicate of [c++ - What is consteval?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53347298/5386374), I wasn't aware of either that question or its relevance to my own.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C++20 added [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) for this express purpose.  A `consteval` function is a `constexpr` function that is guaranteed to be only called at compile time.

Comment: Oh, that looks interesting.  Would it be a valid assumption that `consteval` functions will typically be optimised out entirely during compilation, based on the inherent `inline` specification and the requirement that every call produces a constant expression?

Comment: @justintime that is correct.  It will be evaluated at compile time and only a constant will remain in the binary.