# When is a constexpr evaluated at compile time?

Tags: c++, compilation, language-lawyer, constexpr, c++20

What assurances do I have that a *core constant expression* (as in [expr.const].2) possibly containing constexpr function calls will actually be evaluated at compile time and on which conditions does this depend?

1. The introduction of `constexpr` implicitly promises runtime performance improvements by moving computations into the translation stage (compile time).
2. However, the standard does not (and presumably cannot) mandate what code a compiler produces. (See [expr.const] and [dcl.constexpr]).

These two points appear to be at odds with each other.

**Under which circumstances can one *rely* on the compiler resolving a core constant expression (which might contain an arbitrarily complicated computation) at compile time rather than deferring it to runtime?**

At least under `-O0` gcc appears to actually emit code and call for a constexpr function. Under `-O1` and up it doesn't.

---

Do we have to resort to [trickery](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2pGsLg) such as this, that forces the constexpr through the template system:

```
template <auto V>
struct compile_time_h { static constexpr auto value = V; };
template <auto V>
inline constexpr auto compile_time = compile_time_h<V>::value;

constexpr int f(int x) { return x; }

int main() {
  for (int x = 0; x < compile_time<f(42)>; ++x) {}
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084483/is-there-a-non-indirection-non-hack-way-to-guarantee-that-a-constexpr-function

Comment: @NathanOliver It addresses the same problem, but doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time

Comment: Note C++20 has `consteval` that forces this per-function, so it can help in some cases if you want guarantees without altering use.

Comment: @realestLink Interesting, but that answer asserts that it will be executed at compile time if its result is used in a constexpr. However there is zero evidence to support that claim (unless you count Herb Sutter's edit as official confirmation).

Comment: @bitmask I'm not sure if there is anything in the standard.  When you use a `constexpr` function in something that needs its value at compile time, then the compiler has to call it at compile time because it needs the value.  Otherwise it's up to the compiler when it wants to do the call.

Comment: Dup of [When does a constexpr function get evaluated at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer See my comment above.

Comment: @bitmask Ok, how do you distinguish, using only the Standard, when something was evaluated during compile time and when it wasn't?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer That is a loaded question. You distinguish based on the generated executable. The standard is allowed to impose rules on the compiler's output, even it's diagnostic behaviour.

Comment: @bitmask _The standard is allowed to impose rules on the compiler's output_ Interesting, but I'm not sure it does and the content of "generated executable" is somehow covered in the Standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a `constexpr` function is called and the output is assigned to a `constexpr` variable, it will always be run at compiletime.

Here's a minimal example:

```
// Compile with -std=c++14 or later
constexpr int fib(int n) {
    int f0 = 0;
    int f1 = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int hold = f0 + f1;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = hold;
    }
    return f0; 
}

int main() {
    constexpr int blarg = fib(10);
    return blarg;
}
```

When compiled at `-O0`, gcc outputs the following assembly for `main`:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 55
        mov     eax, 55
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Despite all optimization being turned off, there's never any call to `fib` in the `main` function itself.

This applies going all the way back to `C++11`, however in C++11 the `fib` function would have to be re-written to use conversion to avoid the use of mutable variables.

**Why does the compiler include the assembly for `fib` in the executable sometimes?** A `constexpr` function *can* be used at runtime, and when invoked at runtime it will behave like a regular function.

Used properly, `constexpr` can provide some performance benefits in specific cases, but the push to make everything `constexpr` is more about writing code that the compiler can check for Undefined Behavior.

**What's an example of `constexpr` providing performance benefits?** When implementing a function like `std::visit`, you need to create a lookup table of function pointers. Creating the lookup table every time `std::visit` is called would be costly, and assigning the lookup table to a `static` local variable would still result in measurable overhead because the program has to check if that variable's been initialized every time the function is run.

Thankfully, you can make the lookup table `constexpr`, and the compiler will actually *inline the lookup table into the assembly code for the function* so that the contents of the lookup table is significantly more likely to be inside the instruction cache when `std::visit` is run.

**Does C++20 provide any mechanisms for guaranteeing that something runs at compiletime?**

If a function is `consteval`, then the standard specifies that every call to the function must produce a compile-time constant.

This can be trivially used to force the compile-time evaluation of any constexpr function:

```
template<class T>
consteval T run_at_compiletime(T value) {
    return value;
}
```

Anything given as a parameter to `run_at_compiletime` must be evaluated at compile-time:

```
constexpr int fib(int n) {
    int f0 = 0;
    int f1 = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int hold = f0 + f1;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = hold;
    }
    return f0; 
}

int main() {
    // fib(10) will definitely run at compile time
    return run_at_compiletime(fib(10)); 
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an example of where it works as expected. The question wants to know when one can *rely* on this and some evidence for this (perhaps in form of an official document such as the C++ standard, compiler documentation, etc.).

Comment: This works in every compiler I tested, including IBM PowerPC, gcc, clang, intel C++ compiler, and the MSVC C++ compiler. I've never seen a compiler *not* run it at compiletime, even cases where running the constexpr function is extremely expensive. Aside from that, why do you need a guarantee that this optimization occurs?

Comment: "why do you need a guarantee that this optimization occurs?" I don't like to gamble.

Comment: So I did some more research and `consteval` will do what you want. You can use it to write a function that forces any other `consteval` or `constexpr` function to run at compiletime.

Answer (score 5):

Never; the C++ standard permits almost the entire compilation to occur at "runtime".  Some diagnostics have to be done at compile time, but nothing prevents insanity on the part of the compiler.

Your binary could be a copy of the compiler with your source code appended, and C++ wouldn't say the compiler did anything wrong.

What you are looking at is a QoI - Quality of Implrmentation - issue.

In practice, `constexpr` variables tend to be compile time computed, and template parameters are always compile time computed.

`consteval` can also be used to markup functions.