# Idiomatic way to enforce constexpr-ness of constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, constexpr

Consider the following example code :

```
#include <tuple>
void blah();
int buh;

constexpr auto get() 
{ 
    return std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(&blah, &buh));
}

int main()
{
    get();
}
```

One would expect that since the function `get()` is a constant-expression, it would return a constant.

That's not what happens: `std::make_tuple`, `std::get` are instantiated and called: https://godbolt.org/g/PkHrTp

Now, if we replace the implementation of `get()` by

```
constexpr auto get() 
{ 
    constexpr auto x = std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(&blah, &buh));
    return x;
}
```

We get the expected behaviour : the parameter `x`'s computation is optimized out, even at -O0, and `make_tuple`, `get` are not instantiated, which can be fairly useful to reduce binary bloat.

Is there an idiomatic way to enforce that functions of the form `constexpr auto foo()` always behave like in the second example ?

For now I would resort to :

```
#define constexpr_return(X) do { constexpr auto constexpr_return_x_ = X; return constexpr_return_x_; } while(0)

constexpr_return(std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(&blah, &buh)));
```

for instance but I don't know if this is optimal.

Comment: I recommend perhaps not asking directly for "another library".  While asking for a library recommendation can be considered off-topic, this question seems very valuable without that one part.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even at -O1, everything disappears. I don't expect that your concern turns out to be a problem very often. When it is, that piece of code can be reworked.

Comment: Add `-O3` to the compilation options.

Comment: Looking at unoptimized assembly really isn't helpful.  Even at -O1 all the code is optimized away: https://godbolt.org/g/ExKyML

Comment: I know, I know, but my debug binaries are > 1gb in size (for less than 10 mb at -O3). That's the part I'm trying to improve.

Comment: Your "solution" only works for function without parameters, How about `constexpr int identity(int x) {return x;}` ?

Comment: BTW, `constexpr auto a = get();` would even remove the call to `get()` (both version).

Comment: A `constexpr` function can always be called in a non-`constexpr` context. I believe the only way to force it to be executed as a `constexpr` is to call it in a context that is unambiguously `constexpr` such as you did in the second example by initializing a `constexpr`. Another way would be to assign the result of `get` to a `constexpr`. In the first example, you never use `get` at compile time.

Comment: Jarod42: I don't think it could work with function that have parameters; `identity((int)getch())` for instance. But constexpr functions that don't have parameter are *always* constant expressions, aren't they ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force constexpr to be evaluated at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322386/force-constexpr-to-be-evaluated-at-compile-time)

Comment: What's funny is if you wrap the calls to `get` within `static_assert`, they get optimized out

Answer (score 2):

```
template<auto x>
std::integral_constant< std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x > k{};
```

non-type template parameters must practically be evaluated at compile time.

`k<get()>` or in certain corner cases `k<get()>()` probably does what you want.

This doesn't work for `constexpr` values that cannot be passed as non-type template parameters, but it does work for integers and pointers and function pointers.