# Keep track of instantiated templated types C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am reworking an Entity Component System's Entity Manager. Since components don't have overlapping functionalities, i dont want them to have a shared base I could store.

So i came up with something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Component1{};
class Component2{};
class Component3{};

class Manager{
public:
  template<typename T> static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> component;

  template<typename T> static std::shared_ptr<T> getComponent(int nth){
    return component<T>[nth];
  }

  template<typename T> static std::shared_ptr<T> addComponent(int nth){
    return component<T>[nth] = shared_ptr<T>(new T());
  }

  static void addEntity(){
    // push back a nullptr for every instantiated component<>
  }

  static void removeEntity(int nth){
    // set the nth index of every component<> to nullptr
  }
};

template<typename T>
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> Manager::component = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>();

int main(){
  Manager::component<Component1>;
  Manager::component<Component2>;
  Manager::component<Component3>;

  Manager::addEntity();
  auto cmp2 = Manager::getComponent<Component2>(0);

  Manager::removeEntity(0);

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

How can I iterate over the instantiated components for the two functions? Tried using a vector of type_info's to store the Component types, but I could never the get the proper type out of them to use as a template argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by using a template meta-programming trick to [get a unique ID for your types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708458/template-metaprogram-converting-type-to-unique-number).
Then you could use a map with *unique type ids* instead of your variable template vectors. By introducing polymorphism with a base Component class, coupled with a static_cast (to reduce run-time costs), you could easily re-implement previous *addComponent* and *getComponent* methods. Because of the map access, they're going to be slightly more costly, but in the end you can implement *addEntity* and *removeEntity* by iterating through the map, doing exactly what you wanted.

Here's my implementation of the aforementioned ideas:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

typedef void(*unique_id_type)();

template <typename... Arguments>
struct IdGen {
    static constexpr inline unique_id_type get_unique_id()
    {
        return &IdGen::dummy;
    }

private:
    static void dummy() {};

};

class Component {};
class Component1 : public Component {};
class Component2 : public Component {};
class Component3 : public Component {};

class Manager {
public:
    static std::map<unique_id_type, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>> components;

    template<typename T> static std::shared_ptr<T> getComponent(int nth) {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(components[IdGen<T>::get_unique_id()][nth]);
    }

    template<typename T> static std::shared_ptr<T> addComponent(int nth) {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(components[IdGen<T>::get_unique_id()][nth] = std::shared_ptr<T>(new T()));
    }

    static void addEntity() {
        for (auto& component : components)
            component.second.push_back(nullptr);
    }

    static void removeEntity(int nth) {
        for (auto& component : components)
            component.second[nth] = nullptr;
    }
};

std::map<unique_id_type, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>> Manager::components = {
    { IdGen<Component1>::get_unique_id(), {} },
    { IdGen<Component2>::get_unique_id(), {} },
    { IdGen<Component3>::get_unique_id(), {} },
};

int main() {
    Manager::addEntity();
  auto cmp2 = Manager::getComponent<Component2>(0);

  Manager::removeEntity(0);

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

PS = This code uses C++11 features such as constexpr and list initialization, but since you were already using C++14 (even though you didn't tag your question as C++14), I think that's not a problem.

PS 2 = Since I'm downcasting with a static_cast, you shouldn't use virtual inheritance with your components (read [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484913/why-cant-static-cast-be-used-to-down-cast-when-virtual-inheritance-is-involved)).